# How to safely use a REST API?

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am not a native speaker and can't think of a better title for this question. Feel free to edit it or suggest a better one.

I am trying to use [woocommerce's REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#update-an-order) to update an order status. Currently, when an order is paid via direct bank transfer, a google sheet will be updated with the order ID and amount. I am trying to capture the order ID and update the corresponding order using the API. The simplest way I can think of is to execute something like `myurl.com/myPHP.php?order_id=xxx` when a new row is added to the google sheet. But the problem is, anyone can execute this php file and update the order status accidentally or maliciously. How to avoid this? What is the proper way to use the REST API to update order status?

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce has its REST API endpoints. The endpoint responsible for updating an order's data is protected: you can not use it if you are not authenticated.

There are a few built-in auth methods in WooCommerce REST API; you can learn more about them in the API reference:
https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#authentication

In other words, if you won't provide the API credentials to users that may possibly abuse your API, you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks I am aware of this Doc but need some more detailed explanation.  The steps I can think of to do this is: 1) I write some PHP code which accepts order ID as input 2) the PHP code will authenticate with the API and tell woocommerce to update the order's status 3) the PHP code has a URL like myurl.com/myPHP.php 4) In the google sheet I will create a trigger, when a new row is added, do `UrlFetchApp.fetch('myurl.com/myPHP.php?order_id=xxx')`. This will work, but anyone opening the url myurl.com/myPHP.php?order_id=xxx will have the order status updated even if the order is not paid.